# Is it possible to use a value for a @RequestMapping that is a String but not a String literal?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, enums, string-literals

Is there a way to use an Enum value in a RequestMapping?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example", 
method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final void foo(final HttpServletResponse response,
```

**I want to use a URL value that is already stored in an Enum.**

However, I get compile time errors when I try to put anything except a String literal in the `RequestMapping`.

How does it know the difference between a String literal and a String that is not a String literal ( not sure what that's called ) ?

This is what I tried but it failed at compile time:

```
@RequestMapping(value = FooEnum.Example.getStringValue(), 
method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final void foo(final HttpServletResponse response,
```

I also tried using `String.format` but it doesn't like that either:

```
@RequestMapping(value = String.format("%s", FooEnum.Example.getStringValue()), 
method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final void foo(final HttpServletResponse response,
```

Answer (score 1):

Only literal values can be assigned to annotation attributes because they must be known at compile-time when annotations are processed. Yes, you could use an enum value, where "enum value" is `FooEnum.Example`, but not on an attribute that takes a String value, and you can't call a method on it.

Comment: Not literal values *only*, but rather, constant (at compile-time) values, even expressions such as `"PO" + "ST"` as long as they evaluate to a constant. This is why `RequestMethod.POST` is a valid attribute value in the annotation, but method calls are not.

Answer (score 0):

Tying your URL to an enum value seems funny; I wouldn't want my URLs to change if I updated the enum. Are you actually generating the client links using these same enums? Maybe instead you could just query Spring's Handler bean for the URLs?

There's also the [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), but I only know that it works in @Value annotations, I'm not sure about @RequestMapping

If you're trying to catch multiple URLs in one method, you could use [@PathVariable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-patterns)